# List of Times and Dates a Specific App was Accessed on my Mac

Tags: mac

I would like to know if it is possible to use the terminal in order to get info regarding when a specific app was accessed/closed (history of the app usage). I'm pretty sure that my mac stores this type of info (it uses it for screen time... but screen time only gives you the total time, not the detail regarding when the app was accessed...) but I'm not sure how to access it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Go to Console in the Utilities folder and start it. When the window appears, on the left there is a list of reports. Click on Mac Analytics Data. After clicking this the info will appear in the console window.  Go to the search bar on the top of the console window and enter the name of the program of interest.  See the image below. It shows the window when I performed a session with the app Atom.

[image]

Comment: The Utilities folder is within the Applications folder. Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8YDq.png

Comment: How to filter from the timeline the apps on top? (In other words: exclude the ones running in background?) :)